# Dynamically filter Document Library based on List tiles

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, json-formatting, tiles

For an OOTB modern site page, I know you can dynamically filter the contents of a Document Library part, based on the filter value of a user's selection in a separate List part. You can also customise the List part with JSON to appear as fancy tiles. I'd like the user to click the tile containing their filter value, then see the document library dynamically filter.

How do you use the JSON to specify the List tile's selection action? Making clicking the tile similar to selecting the radial button in a list view?

At the moment, my list tiles don't do anything when clicked. They just change colour when hovered, and look nice. Using the tile view essentially breaks the connected filtering of the Document Library.

Here's the code i borrowed to make my tiles.

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/view-samples/generic-tile-format/tile-view.json

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do dynamically filtering from JSON [view/column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), which is about how we display the documents/items in a list view instead of what documents/items are displayed.

You will need advanced code to do dynamically filtering, such as REST API or SharePoint Framework Extensions.